# Detect frequency change point in audio signal

Tags: android, audio, fft, frequency-analysis

I am recording a fsk signal with a preliminary tone before it. The sample rate is 8000 (samples/sec) and the frequency of the preliminary tone is 440Hz (represnted with 8192 samples - played approximately for 1 second). The signal of the data contains two frequencies, 934Hz for '1' and 510Hz for '0', the encoded message is the char '8' (00111000) each bit is represented using 8192 samples, the signal of the data comes right after the preliminary tone. I used the following code to capture the audio bytes, the only difference is that I am writing them to a ByteArrayOutputStream. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432398/audio-recorder-in-android-process-the-audio-bytes

I am trying to find the point where the frequency shifts from 440Hz of the preliminary tone to the frequency representing the bit '0' (510Hz). The general idea of what I am doing is to decode the message. I am using the FFT algorithm, with a Hann window and the HPS method (http://cnx.org/contents/8b900091-908f-42ad-b93d-806415434b46@2/Pitch_Detection_Algorithms) (I know it's not the best way and there are other algorithms that could perform better, but those are my instructions for now).

Is there any way to detect this point? Can I use the FFT to do it?

Comment: Why are you using HPS ? That makes no sense for a single tone (it is applicable to pitch detection, not tone detection). And if you're going to stubbornly stick with an FFT-based method then you'll need to use overlapping windows in order to capture a change in tone frequency (e.g. 90% overlap), but this is horrendously inefficient.

Comment: The short answer is "yes". Are these sine waves or some guy playing a saxophone? HPS sounds like incredible overkill, I think, but if you have to use it, it will give you the fundamental frequency for the window. What are you asking beyond that?

Comment: @PaulR I used HPS because I had problems with overtones, for example, when I wanted to analyze the frequency 510Hz, I kept getting 1530Hz, so I used it to get the fundamental frequency like Dave said. So the only thing that could give me this point is window overlapping?

Comment: @Dave, the waves frequency change over time, simple BFSK method. 934Hz is the "mark" frequency and the 510Hz is the "space" frequency. Nothing beyond this, just wanted to show what I used so far, thought this might help understand my problem.

Comment: Since you know *a priori* the frequencies of interest you can just ignore any other frequencies, such as harmonics or other distortion products and artefacts. There's no need to analyse the entire spectrum (which is why the FFT approach is overkill in the first place) - just look at the relevant bins and ignore everything else.

Comment: Ok, but are looking for a way to know the exact instant the pitch changes? If so, Paul is right, you will have to use overlapping windows and some acceptable spacing. He's also right there's no need to go this approach in the first place. Way too computationally intensive.

Comment: You probably don't need to know the exact instant.  How many samples in your fourier transform?  Your symbols are so long (8192) samples and you almost definitely aren't using that many in each calculation, so simply doing your transforms successively will probably yield more than enough accuracy to decode your data.  If you calculate over 256 samples you would have 32x oversampling to decode, while serial UARTs typically are build with 16x and can work at 8x. And be sure that your 8 KSPS data comes from a band-limited source, as components well within the audible range will alias with that.

Comment: @just_code_it I'm curious what you were doing that yielded harmonics. How complex are the waveforms? Am I assuming too much to think this is a simple tone? And if so, why wouldn't zero-crossings be a sufficient approach?

Comment: @Dave, I don't really know, I just recived the signal and started FFTing it. This is not a simple tone, it contains several frequencies ( 3 to be exact). How can I use zero-crossing to find this point?

Comment: @PaulR I tried using overlapping windows, I got mixed, and I don't really know how I should write, any suggestions on how should I do this?

Comment: Three tones at one time? That's not the picture I get from your description. When a I said a simple tone, I meant something resembling a sine wave. If that's the case, the distance between samples jumping from positive to negative (or vice versa, i.e., zero-crossings) will be half the wavelength. Given you know the 3 frequencies in advance, it should be easy to estimate which of them is the current one.

Comment: @Dave The 3 frequencies are shown at different time intervals, its a sine wave like you said, for example from t1 to t2 the frequency is 510Hz, from t2 to t3 its 934Hz and so on, depanding on the bit transmitted at some point . About the distances, if I understand correctly, I need to find those points where they cross the X-axis and compute the half wavelength, ok, so I know the formula for wave length is v/f, and for half the wave length is v/2f, so lets say I have the value, but what do I put as the value of v?

Comment: @Dave the distance calculated using the regular formula? https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html If so, then what  is the difference between the x1,x2?

Comment: @just_code_it The distance means the number of samples from one zero-crossing to the next. At 8kHz sample rate (which is really pretty low), a 440Hz wave should cycle in roughly 18 samples. 510Hz ~ 15, 934Hz ~ 8. Zero-crossings should happen about every 9, 7, and 4, respectively. It should be mentioned "zero-crossing" will be relative if your domain is 0-255... then it would be "127-crossing". Counting more cycles should yield better accuracy (so 4 crossings in ~36 samples == 440Hz, etc).

Comment: Also, when you are actually counting, use doubles/floats and round because the frequency doesn't divide evenly into the sample rate.

Comment: @Dave, I  see, but what about the v in the formula?

Comment: You don't need the v/f formula here. I don't think you need to determine a physical length of the wave (as in meters). You are only worried about the frequency.

Comment: @Dave, I tried what you told me, I don't know, it dosn't seem to work, I am counting the amount of samples from one zero cross point to the next one, I don't get the right numbers , somehow I don't think this could work in my case...what about the overlapping windows, after i'll come across a window with a magnitude higher then the one representing the 440Hz, how can I proceed from this section to determine the point where the frequency changes so I could begin my signal analysis?

Answer (score 0):

3 sliding Goertzel filters of length 8192 would work.  Estimate the frequency transition/change times to be at the points where you find a maxima in the difference between the magnitude outputs of any 2 sliding filters.

Also check your tone gemerator and microphone to see if it they have a decent frequency response that low in frequency, which might be why you are detecting overtones instead.